# Finding the First Few Terms of a Complex Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the first four nonzero terms of the power series for $[Log(1-z^2)]^2$ about $z_0=0$.

Hint: Taking derivatives becomes tedious. Instead, try integrating the geometric series.

I am not sure what to do, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hint spelled out a little bit more:

1. You should know by heart the series for $\frac{1}{1-w}$...
2. Integrate this over $w$, mind your constants carefully, and you should find the series for $\log(1-w)$.
3. Substitute $w=z^2$ to find the series for $\log(1-z^2)$...
4. Multiply this series coefficient-wise by itself.  (You'll want to make sure that you've held on to enough terms from 3. to know that you can find the first four non-zero terms; a little trial and error will go a long way here.)

Comment: But, when you integrate the geometric series, you will have a -1 multiplied by $Log(1-w)$ and also I am not sure what you mean by minding the constants?

Comment: @Analysis15 That -1 is trivial to remove.  (And 'mind the constants' because indefinite integration comes with the usual '$+C$' term, so you need to evaluate at $w=0$ to make sure that you have the correct constant term on your Taylor series.)